# Error adding field 'created_at_d' for input string for datetime field in solr with sunspot_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

There are a few questions related to this in stackoverflow but I could not find the answer that work for me, I'm using the last version of solr and for the docs I guess that I don't need a schema.xml and all the solutions told me that I need to add configurations in that file. What I'm missing? This is the error:

"msg":"ERROR: [doc=Announcement 1] Error adding field 'created_at_d'='2018-07-21T00:00:00Z' msg=For input string: \"2018-07-21T00:00:00Z\""

Comment: The server side log should have a proper stacktrace. For production usage you definitely want a schema.xml configured, but for experimenting the schemaless mode is usually good enough. For sunspot you can generate a schema that matches your model for indexing when you run the sunspot generate install command.

Comment: @MatsLindh how would yo ugenerate the schema?  Mine was generated and produced this issue.

Comment: @Alex You handwrite the schema based on which fields you're going to submit and make sure they all have the expected type. The default schema has a set of field types that are usually 90% of what you need, then you create analysis chains for the fields that need special processing after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (in my case at least), that there was an error with the datetime tipe in the solr schema, (you can change it in the web interface), was that the type _d points to double, no to datetime, you can change this and the error will be gone.

Comment: Could you give more details on your solution? I'm having the same issue.